# Large ArrayBuffer crashes with XMLHttpRequest.send()

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to send files using `XMLHttpRequest()` in JavaScript. To do so I use `FileReader` with `readAsArrayBuffer()`.

My code ends with something like that:

```
// 'content' from readAsArrayBuffer
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "url", true);
xhr.send(content);
```

Now, depending of the browser/computer, when I try to use `send(ArrayBuffer)` with a large ArrayBuffer (e.g. a 1GB file), it crashes the browser...

Here is a demo: https://codepen.io/Aymkdn/pen/xXZMwV (just click on the Test button)

This demo creates an ArrayBuffer of 1GB and tries to upload it to some url. I tried it on 3 computers, with last Chrome and Firefox. 100% of the Chrome browsers crashed, and 66% of the Firefox browsers crashed.

Am I missing something here? Is there a size limit to the data passed to `send()` ?

Thanks

Comment: In the server or webconfig,  you have to increase the uploadlimit.  I think the default settings is 5 mb

Comment: Normally when sending large file, you don't load the whole thing into memory, but you load chunks, and send those chunks.  This has other advantages of been able to do resume's, progress bars etc.  It's a bit more work though, as both sides have to agree on a simple protocol.  But well worth it in the long run.

Comment: Alen > this is not due to the server side, the browser crashes before sending it.
Keith > yes but the server I use doesn't support the chunk :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After different tests, it seems that the easy fix is to send a `Blob` instead of an `ArrayBuffer`.

```
// 'content' from readAsArrayBuffer, so it's an ArrayBuffer
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "url", true);
xhr.send(new Blob([content])); // transform ArrayBuffer into Blob
```

In that case the browsers don't crash anymore!